Anime where dying made the character turn into a card?
Trying to find a scene from an anime I watched several years ago. I remember a scene where two characters (maybe villains) were blasted with light or fire. They then turned into cards, which spun in the air for a bit, then fell to the ground. There were two more characters, main characters, I think. One of them, a girl, tries to pick up one of the cards, but it disintegrates in her hand. She was sad. If I remember right, part of how that all worked: if you were a card, you could be brought back to life, but if the card was destroyed, you were dead.
I thought that this would be Cardcaptor Sakura or Tsubasa Reservoir, as I was confident Sakura was that main character. But I've watched through both of these, and I didn't find anything close to that scene, or the theme of dying turning anyone into a card.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about what year this was?  Where did you see it?

Maybe you are searching for Magic Knight Rayearth ?

Is this Shinzo (2000), originally titled Mushrambo in Japan...?

In the world of Mushrambo, human life has all but come to an end. After a deadly virus threatened the extinction of mankind, a new race called the Enterrans was created to preserve life on Earth. However, relations between the Enterrans and their creators did not remain peaceful. Soon a war broke out with the Enterrans fighting against the humans and their robots. Ultimately the Enterrans were the victors of this conflict, renaming Earth as Enterra in honor of their victory.
Before the last vestiges of humanity fell, one of the few remaining scientists put his daughter, Yakumo Shindou, into a sleep chamber. His hope was that his daughter would one day reawaken and find the human sanctuary known as Shinzo, reviving humanity and restoring peace between humans and Enterrans. Centuries have passed since the war; Yakumo now awakens and meets an Enterran named Mashura who pledges to assist in her quest. Also joined by the Enterrans Sago and Kutal, the group must now work to locate Yakumo's missing memories and locate Shinzo. But not every Enterran is as kind as Yakumo's new friends and some are prepared to commit any atrocity to prevent the return of humanity.

As noted in the summary above, the series is about a human girl named Yakumo who wakes up from suspended animation on a future Earth ruled by animal/human hybrids called Enterrans.



She befriends Mushra, Sago and Kutal, three Hyper-Enterrans who can transform into more powerful Hyper Forms. They travel with her, protecting her from hostile Enterrans.




When Enterrans are killed, they disappear and leave behind Encards that contain their spirits. These cards can be absorbed by other Enterrans to transform them into more powerful forms, or to resurrect the fallen Enterrans, provided the cards remain intact.

Encards are what Enterrans become when defeated. The cards can be absorbed or eaten by other Enterrans to gain some of the defeated enterran's powers. If the card is left intact, they can come back to life, if the card is destroyed, the Enterran is gone forever.

In episode 3, "Web of Evil," Mushra (non-lethally) defeats an Enterran named Big Blue and his older brother, who'd kidnapped Yakumo and threatened to kill her. Big Blue and his brother beg to be spared and Yakumo insists that they should be. But when she turns her back, Big Blue kills his brother and absorbs his Encard to become stronger, then attacks her again. Mushra quickly intervenes, killing Big Blue with a spear thrust and then slicing the two Encards left behind in two. Upset by this, Yakumo slaps Mushra and starts crying.

The brothers are soon soundly defeated. They beg to be spared. Yakumo, Sago and Kutal agree to let them go, though Mushra is reluctant. When they were all distracted, Big Blue's older brother betrays him. Killing him to take the power of his brothers Encard. Despite the boost in power, Mushra easily kills the backstabber. He then slash's both brothers cards in half, killing the pair permanently.
Shocked to learn from Sago this means the brothers are now permanently dead. Yakumo lashes out at Mushra. Telling Sago and Kutal that she wont allow Mushra to travel with them any longer. Mushra is left devestated.




